# How to compare date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I got 2 date strings and want to compare them in SQL Server like this:

```
if (convert(timestamp, '6/26/2017 2:07:15.197737 PM') = 
      convert(timestamp, '6/26/2017 2:07:15.187737 AM'))
    print 'y'
else 
    print 'n'
```

Obviously, one date is PM and one date is AM, so they are different, but 'y' is printed out, can someone tell me how to compare this kind of date in SQL Server?

Comment: Note `timestamp` is not actually date time See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is the comparison, the CHECKSUM function is a solid choice.

```
IF CHECKSUM('6/26/2017 2:07:15.197737 PM') = CHECKSUM('6/26/2017 2:07:15.187737 AM')
print 'y'
else 
print 'n'
```

or, give the date/time values you have displayed (higher resolution than DATETIME could accurately compare), you could CAST or CONVERT to DATETIME2(7)

```
if( convert(DATETIME2(7),'6/26/2017 2:07:15.197737 PM') = convert(DATETIME2(7),'6/26/2017 2:07:15.187737 AM'))
print 'y'
else 
print 'n'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want exact comparision including time

```
datetime_column1 = datetime_column2
```

if only compare by date only, convert it to date and compare

```
convert(date, datetime_column1) = convert(date, datetime_column2)
```

Comment: the input is string and I want to compare them as datetime, how to do that?

Comment: use `CAST` or `CONVERT` with style `101` . Looking at your data, you will need to use datetime2